# Beanplot function error in R - confused

Tags: r, plot

The beanplot function keeps showing me this error:

```
Warning message:
In max(unlist(dens["y", ])) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

It has been working fine up until now. I'm really new at R, and I've been trying to work out what the problem is, but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
> data$Treat <- factor(data$Treat, levels = c("Parthenogenetic", "Monoandrous", "Polyandrous"))
> beanplot(Mort~Treat, data=data, col=list("firebrick", "deepskyblue3", "chartreuse4"),
+          ylab="Number of days", xlab="Reproductive mode",
+          las=1, ylim=c(0,80), cutmin = -Inf, cutmax = Inf, log="")
```

Comment: You should generally provide a minimal reproducible example as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). How does `str(data)` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use `labels` not `levels` when you need to rename the categories of `Treat`.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
data <- data.frame(Treat = sample(1:3, n, replace=T),
                   Mort = runif(n,10,70))

data$Treat <- factor(data$Treat, 
              labels = c("Parthenogenetic", "Monoandrous", "Polyandrous"))

library(beanplot)
beanplot(Mort~Treat, data=data, col=list("firebrick", "deepskyblue3", "chartreuse4"),
          ylab="Number of days", xlab="Reproductive mode",
          las=1, ylim=c(0,80), cutmin = -Inf, cutmax = Inf, log="")
```

[image]